# Jalali Calendar

Tags: gnome, calendar

Will `Gnome` add the Jalali (=Persian=Shamsi) calendar as a default calendar, like what KDE has?

I saw that KDE has many calendars that can be used as default instead of Gregorian calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Gnome Shell?
If yes, have a look at this extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/240/persian-calendar/

Comment: It's good. But I mean something that affects all the system, the dates of files (i.e. dates of modified, created...), and even the calendars like `Evolution` . . . (like what's in `KDE`)

Comment: Ah, ok, then I don't really know. In `Language Support` there's a section with number, dates, etc. Did you try look at that?

Comment: Yes, I did. There is nothing about Persian calendar or something like that.