# Some problems in (K)ubuntu 15.04

Tags: kubuntu, bug-reporting, calendar

I installed Kubutu 15.04 some days ago. Rather than beauty and almost big user-facing changes that rarely occurred in recent versions, I see some problem (bugs?!) in it:

1- In previous versions, there was a option in Settings that allows us to specify which (NTFS) drives should auto mounted at start up. That option now is disappeared!

2- People could choose their Calendar system ( Gregorian, Jalali (Persian=Farsi),...) in previous versions. That option is now disappeared!
(see [Jalali Calendar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113233/jalali-calendar))

3- I use Moun package manager. I cannot tell Moun that not treat suggested package as dependencies ones. That option exists, but does not work for me! However, I solved it by a apt.conf's (in /etc/apt/ !) method (see https://askubuntu.com/a/312612/403172).

Is these problems easily solvable? 
Where we should report them if they are bugs?

Comment: If 3 is solved already by an answer here and 2 already has it's own question, please [edit] out this duplication. Thank you!

Comment: I mentioned a bug in Muon. I could not solved 3 by GUI methods.