# Is there Persian calendar in kubuntu yet?

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04, calendar

Before, there was Persian (Jalali) calendar in kubuntu.
I have installed kubuntu 15.04 recently, and it's like there is no Persian calendar any more.

Is this true? Or the way to enable it has changed?

(AND It's definitely not duplicate of this: [Jalali Calendar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113233/jalali-calendar) 
If you know Persian calendar and KDE (kubuntu), you'll know these questions are not the same.)

Answer (score 3):

A Persian (Jalali/Farsi) calendar, it will be called **Gahshomar**, to install it:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:183-amir/gahshomar
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gahshomar
```

[image]

Comment: That's for Gnome, I'm talking about KDE (kubuntu). Thanks BTW.

Comment: No it's not only for Gnome, Gahshomar is told to be woking with variety of OS DEs like Ubuntu, Lubuntu, Debian, ArchLinux etc... did you try install it?

Comment: this is currently the best optimal solution in 15.04 for now.

Comment: I change the time zone but it doesn't change the calendar